# Formatting of Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, iteration

I'm trying to scrape some web content and I'm having a hard time with formatting the output. My code generates a list, then iterates over that list to add more information to it. I'm getting all of the data that I need, but when I try to save it to a CSV I'm getting more than one list per line. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Here's my code:

```
def getPeople(company, url, filename):
  persList = []
  category = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
  code = urllib.urlopen(url)
  html = code.read()
  unic = unicode(html, errors='ignore')
  tree = etree.parse(StringIO(unic), parser)
  personNames = tree.xpath('//a[@class="person"]/text()')
  personUrls = tree.xpath('//a[@class="person"]/@href')
  for i, j in zip(personNames, personUrls):
    personInfo = (company, category, i, j)
    internal = list(personInfo)
    persList.append(internal)
  result = list(persList)
  return result

def tasker(filename):
  peopleList = []
  companyNames = getCompanies(filename, '//a[@class="company"]/text()')
  companyUrls = getCompanies(filename, '//a[@class="company"]/@href')
  for i, j in zip(companyNames, companyUrls):
    peopleLinks = getPeople(i, j, filename)
    internal = list(peopleLinks)
    peopleList.append(internal)
  output = csv.writer(open("test.csv", "wb"))
  for row in itertools.izip_longest(*peopleList):
    output.writerow(row)
  return peopleList
```

Here's a sample of the output:

```
[[['3M', 'USA', 'Rod Thomas', 'http://site.com/ron-thomas'], ['HP', 'USA', 'Todd Gack', 'http://site.com/todd-gack'], ['Dell', 'USA', 'Phil Watters', 'http://site.com/philwatt-1'], ['IBM', 'USA', 'Mary Sweeney', 'http://site.com/ms2105']], [['3M', 'USA', 'Tom Hill', 'http://site.com/tomhill'], None, ['Dell', 'USA', 'Howard Duck', 'http://site.com/howard-duck'], None], [['3M', 'USA', 'Neil Rallis', 'http://site.com/nrallis-4'], None, None, None]]
```

This makes for an ugly CSV file that's difficult to read. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:
This is what I'd like the output to look like.

```
[['3M', 'USA', 'Rod Thomas', 'http://site.com/ron-thomas'], ['HP', 'USA', 'Todd Gack', 'http://site.com/todd-gack'], ['Dell', 'USA', 'Phil Watters', 'http://site.com/philwatt-1'], ['IBM', 'USA', 'Mary Sweeney', 'http://site.com/ms2105'], ['3M', 'USA', 'Tom Hill', 'http://site.com/tomhill'], ['Dell', 'USA', 'Howard Duck', 'http://site.com/howard-duck'], ['3M', 'USA', 'Neil Rallis', 'http://site.com/nrallis-4']]
```

Comment: Can you please post what your desired format is?

Comment: Good question. I just updated the question to include the output that I'd like to see.

Comment: In general, for this kind of task, you want to separate the code that navigates the website from your logic.  Write functions, name them appropriately, and them call them from a function that controls your logic.

Comment: @kreativitea That's good feedback, I appreciate you saying so. I'm self-taught & don't get much feedback on my code/style. I'll think through how I could improve. In this example the lists make it more challenging for me. It would have been easier to do in R (for me anyway), but I'm forcing myself to get more comfortable with Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your line:

```
peopleList.append(internal)
```

You are appending one list into another. This makes the internal list become a member of the peopleList.

Instead you want to extend the peopleList. That's how you combine two lists.

So it would be:

```
peopleList.extend(internal)
```

Comment: This is so simple I'm smacking my head. This does exactly what I wanted. I was wondering why my output had `None` in it, and how I was going to address that. This simple change took care of that issue as well. Thanks for the tip!